# How to test wcf soap service using POSTMAN?

Tags: web-services, wcf

Hi I am developing XML Soap services using WCF. My requirement is to update some database table. I have one method to update values in the db. Below is my service.

```
  [ServiceContract]
public interface IOpportunity
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "postmethod/updateOpportunity")]
    bool updateOpportunity(opportunityActivity obj);
}
[DataContract]
public class opportunityActivity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityStatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunityserviceType { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Missing method]

Below is my xml.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s="http://localhost:39512/Opportunity.svc">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <s:request>
       <opportunityID>1-1D5SJX</opportunityID>
       <opportunityStatus>Completed</opportunityStatus>
       <opportunityserviceType>LEASE_REQUEST</opportunityserviceType>
      </s:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

when i i try as shown above i get 400 bad request error.May i know am i following correct approach to test the service? Can someone correct me if i am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is not correct - you cannot construct the soap request manually. Use some tooling to do it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a soap message to the service endpoint.

Eg

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s="http://myNamespace/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <s:request>
          ....
      </s:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To get hold of a soap message you should use the service endpoint definition and use [some tooling](https://www.soapui.org/) to generate a valid request.

Additionally, you should not be sending data to the endpoint address with `?wsdl` as part of the address. It should only be the endpoint address.

Comment: Thank you tom. xmlns:s="http://myNamespace/" should be replaced by xmlns:s="http://RayaSoapService/" right?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole it depends on how you have defined your endpoint. It's notoriously difficult to manually hack a soap request together from scratch. It's far easy to let a tool do it for you.

Comment: Okay thank you. When i run the application i am missing the method name. May i know what i am missing? I have attached screenshot above.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole - what application are you running? If it's SOAPUI then look at this: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole - *Same wcf application. When I run it should list method names right?* - yes that's another way to get a soap request for the endpoint. If it's not listed then you have a problem with your service. You should create a new question for this problem separately.